# for i, data in enumerate(trainloader) is taking to much time to execute

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to train a model of GAN using PyTorch and the issue is that the code is taking to much time when it comes to the second loop (for), I even took just a part of the dataset and still the same problem.

To get a better idea about the whole code, here you can find my notebook : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1STi87M2pNjVOt-LGc6rZ5-kpAf0NwFAm?usp=sharing

As well as the dataset : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LpEJwa_OlirZV2mK9vdxNSWZor-AFty_?usp=sharing

The part of the code with the problem is located in the last cell of my notebook. Here is the code with the problem (if you have any idea about this issue just let me know Thanks you)

Thank you and I appreciate anyone who can help or not with anything he could (Thank you)

```
import os
import copy
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from dataset import NTUSkeletonDataset
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
#import GAN
from torch.autograd import Variable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

# Root directory for dataset
dataroot = "Data/nturgb+d_skeletons"

# Batch size during training
batch_size = 5

# Size of z latent vector (i.e. size of generator input)
latent_dim = 20

# Number of training epochs
num_epochs = 200

# Learning rate for optimizers
lrG = 0.00005
lrD = 0.00005

clip_value = 0.01
n_critic = 20

trainset = NTUSkeletonDataset(root_dir=dataroot, pinpoint=1, merge=2)
trainloader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                         shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if cuda else "cpu")
Tensor = torch.cuda.FloatTensor if cuda else torch.FloatTensor

generator = Gen0(latent_dim).to(device)
discriminator = Dis0().to(device)

optimizer_G = torch.optim.RMSprop(generator.parameters(), lr=lrG)
optimizer_D = torch.optim.RMSprop(discriminator.parameters(), lr=lrD)

epoch_loss = np.zeros((num_epochs, 3, len(trainloader)//n_critic+1))

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    j = 0
    print("Boucle 1")
    epoch_start = time.time()
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
        print("something")
        size = (-1, data.size(-1))
        data = data.reshape(size)
        print
        optimizer_D.zero_grad()

        real_skeleton = Variable(data.type(Tensor)).to(device)

        critic_real = -torch.mean(discriminator(real_skeleton))
        # critic_real.backward()

        # sample noise as generator input
        z = torch.randn(real_skeleton.size(0), latent_dim).to(device)

        # Generate a batch of fake skeleton
        fake_skeleton = generator(z).detach()

        critic_fake = torch.mean(discriminator(fake_skeleton))
        # critic_fake.backward()

        loss_D = critic_real + critic_fake
        loss_D.backward()

        optimizer_D.step()

        # clip weights of discriminator
        for p in discriminator.parameters():
            p.data.clamp_(-clip_value, clip_value)

        # Train the generator every n_critic iterations:
        if i % n_critic == n_critic - 1:
            optimizer_G.zero_grad()

            # Generate a batch of
            gen_skeleton = generator(z)
            # adversarial loss
            loss_G = -torch.mean(discriminator(gen_skeleton))

            loss_G.backward()
            optimizer_G.step()

            for k, l in enumerate((loss_G, critic_real, critic_fake)):
                epoch_loss[epoch, k, j] = l.item()
            j += 1

    epoch_end = time.time()
    print('[%d] time eplased: %.3f' % (epoch, epoch_end-epoch_start))
    for k, l in enumerate(('G', 'critic real', 'critic fake')):
        print('\t', l, epoch_loss[epoch, k].mean(axis=-1))

    if epoch % 20 == 19:
        m = copy.deepcopy(generator.state_dict())
        torch.save(m, 'gen0_%d.pt' % epoch)

np.save('gen0_epoch_loss.npy', epoch_loss)
```